# how can I prove this rigorously by using Mathematical analysis? $(|f'(x)| \le1 \iff |f(s)-f(t)| \le |s-t|)$

Tags: calculus, analysis

> For given $f$ which is differentiable in $\mathbb R$,
>
> (a) $\forall x \in \mathbb R, |f'(x)| \le 1$
>
> (b) $\forall s,t \in \mathbb R, |f(s)-f(t)| \le |s-t|$
>
> Show that (a) and (b) is iff.

How can I show that (a) and (b) is iff by using mathematical analysis? I can prove this by using MVT, but I want to know the rigorous proof.

Comment: what is the difference between "I can prove this" and a "rigourous proof"? And its not an iff, consider $f(x)=|x|$

Comment: (a) implies (b) uses the mean-value theorem. (b) implies (a) is generally false unless you assume $f$ is differentiable everywhere.

Comment: IThat is my fault, sorry.

Comment: I was not familiar with MathJax, so there was a mistake in the process of writing.

Answer (score 0):

(b) implies (a).
Assume
(i) $f$ is differentiable at $x$
(ii) $\forall s,t \in \mathbb R, |f(s)-f(t)| \le |s-t|$.

Let $h \in \mathbb R$.  By (ii)
$$
\left|\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}\right|
=\frac{|f(x+h)-f(x)|}{|(x+h)-x|} \le 1
$$
and by (i)
$$
|f'(x)|=\left|\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}\right|
=\lim_{h\to 0}\left|\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}\right| \le 1
$$